# Can you pass an extension method as a function argument in Dart?

Tags: dart, extension-methods

Is there a way to pass an extension method as a function argument?

I'd like to pass an extension method to a `.map` method like a static function if it's possible.

Something like this:

```dart
extension Add10 on int {
  int add10() {
    return this + 10;
  }
}

int add100(int x) => x + 100;

// I'd like to do something like this
[1, 2, 3, 3, 5].map(Add10.add10);

// Like I could do with a regular function
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5].map(add100);

// instead of
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5].map(x => x.add10());
```

Is this possible?

In other words, can an extension method on `int` that returns an `int` satisfy the signature

```dart
int Function(int)
```

like my `add100` function can?

Or are extension methods always treated more like a class that must wrap the value before making the call?

Comment: You wouldn't be able to do what you want with an actual instance method, and an extension method isn't any different in that regard.

Comment: @jamesdlin - Thank you for the comment, that is what I was wondering. I was looking at other languages that feature extension methods - C# and Kotlin - and each mentions (just like Dart) that they are resolved statically. Both C# and Kotlin seem to offer a way to call the extension method like a regular function - i.e. an extension on int can satisfy a function signature `(int) -> Thing`. I played with Swift too and it seems like theirs is more like Dart. Thank you!

Comment: Dart does allow you to call extension methods like a regular function: `Add10(someInt).add10` would be an `int Function()`, but that still wouldn't help you use it directly with `.map`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, not like that.

An extension method is like an instance method in this regard. You can't extract an instance method from `int` int to a function, pass it somewhere else, and then call that method on other integers.

Just like an instance method, you need to do:

```dart
[1, 2, 3, 3, 5].map((x) => x.add10())
```

That's one situation where extension methods are less usable than the static helper function they're intended to replace. As @eugene-kuzmenko points out, you can make the extension method a static function instead (not necessarily inside an `extension` declaration), and then you can tear it off an pass it as an argument, because then it's not inherently tied to a single receiver, but it takes the number to act on as an argument, like `Iterable.map` expects.

If you are going to turn the result of the map into a `List` anyway, I'd probably just use a literal:

```dart
var numbers = [1, 2, 3, 3, 4];
var newNumbers = [for (var x in numbers) x.add10()];
```

It looks slightly more cumbersome, but in practice I find it much more convenient to not have to write functions literals (and it also works with asynchronous operations then).

Answer (score 0):

**Technically** you can use a static function inside extension

```
[1, 2, 3, 3, 5].map(**Add10.add10**);
```

So you can change your extension method(and function signature)

```
extension Add10 on int {
  static int add10(int i) {
    return i + 10;
  }
}
```

**But I don't think it's a good idea**